# MySQL stored procedure 1064 Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

For the life of me, I can't figure out why I'm getting this error:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'NULL' at line 1

I'm calling a simple stored procedure with some variables passed in. What you don't see here is the setting of the delimiter to //, but that's done as well.

Thanks much!

```
SET @dest_database                   = 'my_db';
SET @table_category_management_pages = 'category_management_pages';


 CREATE PROCEDURE category_management_pages(
    IN in_name varchar(255),
    IN in_display varchar(255),
    IN in_notes varchar(255),
    IN in_order INT,
    IN in_title varchar(255),
    IN in_access_name varchar(255)
  )
  BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
      WHERE
      TABLE_SCHEMA = @dest_database AND
      TABLE_NAME   = @table_category_management_pages AND
      COLUMN_NAME  = 'key_hash'
    ) THEN
      # Add UNIQUE index on key_hash
      SET @myPrep = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', @dest_database, '`.`', @table_category_management_pages, '` ADD COLUMN `key_hash` varchar(255) NULL, ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`key_hash`);');
      prepare stmt from @myPrep;
      execute stmt;
    END IF;

    # Update key_hash to latest hash
    SET @myPrep = CONCAT('UPDATE `', @dest_database, '`.`', @table_category_management_pages, '` 
      SET `key_hash` = md5(`name`)');
     prepare stmt from @myPrep;
     execute stmt;

END//
```

Comment: Did you declare **@myPrep** somewhere before using it?

Comment: I don't think it's required. I have another procedure that runs fine with the same syntax in that regard.

Comment: if using a local variable, it **must** be declared before usage. If using a global variable, no declaration is needed, because it has already been declared previously by the system. Also, check your mysql installation. The newer versions have tightened up some lax rules in previous versions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Ill hunt around a bit and declare it and see what happens.

Comment: Place `DELIMITER //` before `CREATE PROCEDURE...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I found out why the prepared statement wasn't working and it is something really simple dumb, but may affect others in the future. At our company, we have a habit of lining up all the equal signs when declaring variables (see edits above). Well, it seems like MySQL doesn't like whitespace in this manner, so the global variables weren't being passed in the prepared statement correctly.  By changing the declaration to this:

```
/* Globals */
SET @dest_database = 'my_db';
SET @table_category_management_pages = 'category_management_pages';
```

...worked out fine. Go figure. Both suggestion in the comments were good, but in the end it was something due to whitespace. Very frustrating, but I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: It seems like there had to be something other than just whitespace involved; MySQL doesn't have a problem with the spaced-out equal signs, and you can confirm this by setting the variables and then `SELECT @dest_database, @table_category_management_pages;` to confirm that the assignment works... but the error message does indicate that something was null since concat() returns null if any argument is null, and `PREPARE STMT FROM @foo` will return that exact error if @foo is null. I assume you know those aren't actually "global" variables, they're user-defined variables, with session scope.